# Slicing and finding the volume

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, volume, slice

I have four columns, namely **`x,y,z,zcosmo`**. The range of zcosmo is **`0.0<zcosmo<0.5`**.

**For each x,y,z, there is a zcosmo.**

When **`x,y,z`** are plotted, this is how they look. 
[image]

I would like to find the volume of this figure. If I **slice it into 50 parts (in ascending zcosmo order)**, so that **each part resembles a cylinder**, I can **add them up to get the final volume.**

The volume of the sliced cylinders would be `pi*r^2*h`, in my case **`r = z/2 & h = x`**

The slicing for example would be like, 
**`x,z for 0.0<zcosmo<0.01`** find this volume **V1**. Then **`x,z for 0.01<zcosmo<0.02`** find this volume **V2** and so on until zcosmo=0.5

I know to do this manually (which of course is time consuming) by saying:

```
r1 = z[np.logical_and(zcosmo>0.0,zcosmo<0.01)] / 2 #gives me z within the range 0.0<zcosmo<0.01
h1 = x[np.logical_and(zcosmo>0.0,zcosmo<0.01)] #gives me x within the range 0.0<zcosmo<0.01

V1 = math.pi*(r1**2)*(h1)
```

Here r1 and h1 should be `r1 = ( min(z) + max(z) ) / 2.0` and `h1 = max(x) - min(x)`, i.e **the max and min values so that I get one volume for each slice**

How should I create a code that calculates the 50 volume slices within the zcosmo sliced ranges??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
volumes = list()
for index in range(0, 50):
    r = z[np.logical_and(zcosmo>index * 0.01, zcosmo<index * 0.01 + 0.01)] / 2
    h = x[np.logical_and(zcosmo>index * 0.01, zcosmo<index * 0.01 + 0.01)]

    volumes.append(math.pi*(r**2)*(h))
```

At the end, volumes will be a list containing the volumes of the 50 cylinders.

You can use `volume = sum(volumes)` to get the final volume of the shape.

Comment: I only need `r1` and `h1` to be the `max` and `min` values so that I get one volume for each slice and not all 50 values for each slice.

Comment: I do not understand what you are tring to achive after the edit. Please explain more in detail.

Comment: I figured it out! I wanted the volume for the slice, which we get by using the height and radius of the slice.